240 volt EV charger worked then stopped working
My EV charger works for about 6 months then stopped.
I checked voltage going to the charger and got 120 and 114. On the two hots.
The company sent me a second charger.
Also no power lights come on.
So I checked the voltage across the phase s I only got 9 volts.
All the other appliances that need 240 in the house work fine.  Again the charger work fine for 6 months.
The wiring was not changed in the box.
Even though I get 120 and 114 or so to the hots could the breaker be bad?
Up date..
I checked across the phases coming out of the breaker.  I had 246 volts so that was fine no problem with the breaker then I checked the connection where two 220 lines were spliced.
When I was on twisting some electrical tape that covered the wire nut one of the wires fell out of the nut so it was a bad connection.
I'm guessing when I checked each wire in the EV charger.  I was getting a feedback loop from one wire to the other through the device so that would explain why one of the lines showed 126 and the other showed 114 I'm pretty sure.
I'm trying to get the electrician who did this to come out for free and fix it I think that's a minimal expectation right.

A better bet would a loose/dirty connection, so check those first and check the voltage at the breaker.  You should get ~240 volts between the two hots.

Probably some connection not torqued properly (neither too tight nor too loose) and has loosened due to thermal cycling since car charging is a high percentage long-duration load. Only way I'd be suspecting the breaker is if it's not listed for the panel (in which case it would need to be replaced regardless of voltage output), but @crip659's test will confirm/deny it as being operating correctly.

Well I think I found it I took the panel off coming out of the breaker I had 246 across phases.

I moved OP's misplaced update into OP's question. The meta discussion on where updates go hasn't been decided by the mods yet, but OP can also make a self answer and move it there, too.
